# Which functions map dense subsets onto subsets?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I was wondering about the following:

Let $X$ be a normed space and $A$ be a dense subset in $X$. What properties must a function $f$ necessarily have, so that we have that $f(A)$ is dense in $Y$, if we have $f:X \rightarrow Y$. I think it is pretty clear that the function should be bijective? Do we need more(continuous?)

Comment: Do you want the image of *every* dense subset to be dense, or just the one?

Comment: of every dense subset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about necessary conditions. But if $f$ is continuous and $f[X]$ is dense in $Y$, you already know that $f[A]$ is dense in $Y$, by standard arguments. So bijective is not necessary. Of course $f[X]$ must be dense (as it contains $f[A]$).

Comment: what do you mean by $f[Y]$?

Comment: Corrected to $f[X]$